# How can I call RestFull webservice Java use ajax html

Tags: java, html, ajax

How call restfull webservice java use ajax html, I create simple webservice in java, I want to POST data into database use html ajax with call webservice java eclipse, but show error in my java program, how can I fix it my code?

This is My Entity PayrollModel

```
@Entity
@Table(name="payroll")
public class PayrollModel implements Serializable {

private static final long SerialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private long idPayroll;

@Column(name="name_file")
private String nameFile;

@Column(name="status")
private String status;

@Column(name="creationdate")
private Date creationDate;

@Column(name="company_id")
private String companyId;

public long getIdPayroll() {
    return idPayroll;
}

public void setIdPayroll(long idPayroll) {
    this.idPayroll = idPayroll;
}

public String getNameFile() {
    return nameFile;
}

public void setNameFile(String nameFile) {
    this.nameFile = nameFile;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Date getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
}

public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
}

public String getCompanyId() {
    return companyId;
}

public void setCompanyId(String companyId) {
    this.companyId = companyId;
}

public static long getSerialversionuid() {
    return SerialVersionUID;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PayrollModel [idPayroll=" + idPayroll + ", nameFile=" + nameFile + ", status=" + status
            + ", creationDate=" + creationDate + ", companyId=" + companyId + "]";
}



 }
```

This is my Controller

```
@PostMapping(path="/save")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
PayrollModel savepayroll(@RequestBody PayrollModel body) {

    body.setStatus("0");
    body.setCreationDate(new Date());
    return payrollRepoSitory.save(body);
}
```

This is My Html and Ajax code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Belajar Dasar Ajax</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Kirim Data dengan Ajax</h1>
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return sendData()">
    <p>
        <label>Nama File</label>
        <input type="text" id="name_file" placeholder="name file">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Company Id</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="company_id" placeholder="isi company id"></textarea>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Kirim" />
</form>

<script>
    function sendData() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "http://localhost:8181/save";

        var data = JSON.stringify({
            title: document.getElementById("name_file").value,
            companyid: document.getElementById("company_id").value,
            userId: 1
        });

        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        xhr.onload = function () {               
            console.log (this.responseText);
        };

        xhr.send(data);
        return false;
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is My Messages error

```
   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "name_file" violates not-null constraint
   Detail: Failing row contains (null, 0, 2019-11-21 15:50:15.569+07, null, 32).
   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2497) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2233) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:310) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:446) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:370) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:149) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:124) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3106) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3699) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:292) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:702) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:688) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:368) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:554) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.bsm.payroll.controller.PayrollController.savepayroll(PayrollController.java:64) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_211]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_211]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_211]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `name` attribute for your both `input`. And replace the following line

`title` to  `nameFile` and `companyid` to `companyId`

Comment: @UlfaHartina can post your `PayrollModel` class ?

Comment: i have do post my PayrollModel @sudhir Ojha